# Почему в Qt creator,когда подключаюсь к базе данных(MSSQL),не выполняются запросы,хотя в SQL server он выполняется?

Tags: c++, qt

**Вот кода,который подключает меня к базе данных**

```
void login::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QString servername="(local)";
    QString dbname="People";
    QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setConnectOptions();
    QString dsn =QString("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%1;DATEBASE=%2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;").arg(servername).arg(dbname);
    db.setDatabaseName(dsn);
    db.setUserName("Никита-ПК/Никита");
    db.setPassword("");
    if(db.open()&&(ui->lineEdit->text()=="123")&&(ui->lineEdit_2->text()=="123"))
    {

        mes->setText("Connect!!!");
         close();
    }
    else
    {
        mes->setText("No connect");
    }
    mes->show();
}

**Вот код,который создает запрос**
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

     QSqlQuery query;
   //  QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
     int        id = 0;
     QString    firstName;
     QString    secondName;
     QString       age;
     mes=new QMessageBox();
     if (!query.exec("SELECT * FROM Person"))
     {
          mes->setText("Bad");
          //сlose();
          mes->show();

     }
     else
     {
           mes->setText("God!!!");
             mes->show();
             while (query.next())
             {
                 id  = query.value(0).toInt();
                 firstName  = query.value(1).toString();
                 secondName = query.value(2).toString();
                 age= query.value(3).toString();
                 if(id==1)
                 {
                   ui->lineEdit->setText(firstName);
                   ui->lineEdit_2->setText(secondName);
                   ui->lineEdit_3->setText(age);
                 }
             }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня не выполнялось подключение,так как после подключения к серверу я  работал в master(что странно хотя я указывал имя базы данных),в результате после того,как я добавил строку  query.exec("use People;");--тем самым указав еще раз с какой базой данных нужно работать,все заработало

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять причину ошибок драйвера SQL, воспользуйтесь методом [QSqlQuery::lastError](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastError).

```
qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
```

В вашем случае я не вижу, как объект QSqlQuery связан с базой данных. Попробуйте воспользоваться [этим конструктором](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2) и передайте в качестве параметра вашу базу данных:

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
```

Разумеется, этот объект надо как-то вытащить из метода `login::on_pushButton_clicked`.

Comment: Делал,но выскакивает ошибка  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Недопустимое имя обьекта"Person".[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]  Курсор не обьявлен.QODBC3:Unable to execute statement

Comment: @Nikita, значит, в базе действительно нет сущности `Person`.

Comment: есть,я запускал,через Microsoft SQL Server managment studio 17 и делал выборку